# Backbone Subclass a Model causes error in IE8

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, internet-explorer-8

i have a strange problem using backbone.js and i don't know how to resolve it.

This problem is only appearing on IE8 , on IE9+ it works fine.

I have a class :

```
    window.List= Backbone.Model.extend({
            ...


            ...

            })
```

And a subclass:

```
    window.HomeList= List.extend({
            ...


            ...

            })
```

I get this error from IE8 :
Object doesn't support this property or method. The referring line is :

```
    window.HomeList= List.extend({
```

It only works if i start a new model copying all methods from the first Class.

Do you have any idea ?

Comment: Agree with @muistooshort rename to `Klass`.

Comment: Hello, I just edited my post with the real Class names :)

Comment: And no its not a trailing comma problem I just checked everything :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok so i found out why it didnt work on IE8. The problem was not backbone.

Changed this:

```
   window.HomeList= List.extend({
        ...


        ...

        })
```

To this:

```
   var HomeList= List.extend({
        ...


        ...

        })
```

Now it works. Don't know why but on IE8 I can't use window to store the variable.